# Can I edit my Music playlist on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, iphone, apple-music, ios

I have an iPhone 5s running iOS 10.0.2.  My iTunes version is 12.5.3.17.  I have synced them together but I cannot see my Music playlist in iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to check and see if you are syncing playlists through iTunes.  You can verify that here:

[image]

If you have that, your playlists may be in iTunes Cloud library, which you have to enable here:

[image]

Comment: My iPhone's Music page did not have the same set of options in my iTunes.  But the playlist showed up when I enabled iCloud Music Library in General Preferences.  Thanks!